# Thumbnail of *.mp4 with size and drawtext

Tags: ffmpeg, size

I am trying to create a thumbnail with the size of 200 and a drawtext.
Unfortunately I have problems to create this thmumbnail with both options.
Thumbnail with size is working:
ffmpeg -i xyz.mp4 -ss 00:00:05 -vframes 1 -filter:v scale=280:-1 xyz.jpg
Thumbnail with drawtext is working too:
fmpeg -i xyz.mp4 -vf drawtext=text=bla:x=20:y=20:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white -ss 00:00:05.000 -vframes 1 xyz.jpg
But a combination of both is not working. I geht always the error the -filter, -vf/-af an not be used together.
Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try using -filter_complex, with each different filter separated by a comma. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i xyz.mp4 -filter_complex "scale=280:-1, drawtext=text=bla:x=20:y=20:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white" -ss 00:00:05.000 -vframes 1 xyz.jpg
```